# EF map tables using XML file

Tags: xml, entity-framework

I have two db's and I need to import data from one to another. But the problem is that user needs to define mapping on the xml file and accordingly that I need to map them and import data also I need to check if there is a new property added to one DB table and popup a message to user to update the mapping xml file.

My question is is this possible cos I did searched on the web but I wasn't able to find a clue. If any one have idea of doing this please let me know. That would be a great help. Below is the my sample xml file.

```
<Field targetField="PO_DATE">Orderdate</Field> 
<Field targetField="CUSTCHAR2">Orderdate</Field> 
<Field targetField="PROMOTION_CODE">Couponname</Field> 
<Field targetField="">Coupon_discount</Field> 
<Field targetField="TAX_AMOUNT">Tax</Field>
```